# What are the base materials of Chain Mail Armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm aware the anvil combines an item with its base materials to repair it. What are the base materials of chainmail so I can repair my Respiration I Chain Helm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can repair a chain armor with iron ingots.

Here's the [wiki paragraph](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Armor):

> Anvils can also repair a piece of armor using units of that armor's
> base material. Chain armor can be repaired in this manner by using
> iron ingots.

Answer (score 1):

There are three different answers to this question:

- For use in anvil repairing, iron ingots are used.
- For use in crafting table repairing, another peice of the same armor must be used.
- For use in crafting the armor, fire must be used (unobtainable in Survival).

To obtain Chainmail armor, one must either kill a mob wearing such armor or trade with villagers.

Comment: Actually, in crafting, another piece of the armor would be used to repair it, not fire; same for any other piece of armor repaired by crafting. You use the armor, not the material used when repairing by crafting.

Comment: @Unionhawk Forgot about that, I meant actual crafting of the armor. See the edit ^